# What does base value do in int function?

Tags: python

I've read the official doc https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int, but still confused.

I've tried some command on my terminal, I find some rules, but still not quite clear about it. Hope someone with more knowledge about this can explain it further.

Below are my examples and findings:

```
int('0', base=1)
ValueError: int() base must be >= 2 and <=36

int('3', base=2)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2:

int('3', base=4)
3

int('33', base=4)
15

int('333', base=4)
63

int('353', base=4)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 4:
```

I find two rules here:

1. the single string numbers must be smaller than the base number.
2. the `int()` will return a number which equals `(n)*(base^(n-1)) + (n-1)*(base^(n-2)) + ... + 1*(base^0)`

Are there any other hidden rules than this, and what kind of problem the base is designed to solve?

Comment: `What kind of problem is base designed to solve?` = highly useful in number theory which has applications in cryptography (RSA), coding (error detection and correction), etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It does exactly what it says - converts a string to integer in a given numeric base. As per the documentation, `int()` can convert strings in any base from 2 up to 36. On the low end, base 2 is the lowest useful system; base 1 would only have "0" as a symbol, which is pretty useless for counting. On the high end, 36 is chosen arbitrarily because we use symbols from "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" (10 digits + 26 characters) - you could continue with more symbols, but it is not really clear what to use after z.

"Normal" math is base-10 (uses symbols "0123456789"):

```
int("123", 10)  # == 1*(10**2) + 2*(10**1) + 3*(10**0) == 123
```

Binary is base-2 (uses symbols "01"):

```
int("101", 2)   # == 1*(2**2) + 0*(2**1) + 1*(2**0) == 5
```

"3" makes no sense in base 2; it only uses symbols "0" and "1", "3" is an invalid symbol (it's kind of like trying to book an appointment for the 34th of January).

```
int("333", 4)   # == 3*(4**2) + 3*(4**1) + 3*(4**0)
                # == 3*16 + 3*4 + 3*1
                # == 48 + 12 + 3
                # == 63
```

Comment: Amazing answer. I never got at university a nice explanation like that. This is going to be useful in my whole life, not just in programming.

Comment: The above is a must read for those who want to understand the solution of the add-binary leetcode problem : https://leetcode.com/problems/add-binary/

Answer (score 7):

The `base` value tells python to interpret the given string to be a value of a different base.

For example, the `1011` in base 2 is 11. Thus, `int('1011', 2)` returns `11`.
On the other hand, `1011` in base 3 is 31. Thus, `int('1011', 3)` returns `31`.

Decimals are in base 10, which is why the default value of `base` is `10`.

A fun side-effect of choosing a numeric base, is that there does not exist a digit in that system that is higher than (or equal to) the base itself. This is why we do not have a digit for ten in the decimal system, while the hexadecimal system (base 16) uses the digit `A` for ten. This is why you were getting errors for asking a number with the digit `5` to be interpreted in base 4.

Answer (score 5):

The base is the number of distinct  basic elements or digits in a number system.

Base 2 has 0 and 1 and can be represented in electronics as an on and off.

Base 10 has the familiar 10 digits 0..9

Any integer can be expressed in any of the bases but the string of symbols will be different.  For instance in base 2 1111 = 15 in base 10

The ability to choose the base converting to or from strings allows software to accept input in different bases and translate bases if appropriate.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix

Answer (score 4):

The `int()` function can convert an integer in a base (or [radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix)) other than 10 passed as a string, where the second parameter is the base of the number in the string, and the result will be an integer in base 10. For example, all the following string values will result in the integer `42`:

```
int('42')        # by default, it's base 10
=> 42
int('42', 10)    # same as above
=> 42
int('101010', 2) # base 2 (binary)
=> 42
int('2A', 16)    # base 16 (hexadecimal)
=> 42
```