# Python casting int("string", integer)

Tags: python

What is the logic behind

```
     int("string", integer)
```

for example:

```
     int("220", 3)
```

yields

```
      24
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int). First result for `int pythopn` on Google.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190060/what-does-base-value-do-in-int-function

Comment: the second parameter is the base to use

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert integer to a string in a given numeric base in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/convert-integer-to-a-string-in-a-given-numeric-base-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

The optional integer is the numeric base to use in converting the string (defaults to base 10).

```
220 base 3 = 2 * (3**2) + 2 * (3**1) + 0 * (3**0)
           = 2*9 + 2*3 + 0*1
           = 18 + 6 + 0
           = 24
```

Answer (score 0):

the int() method in python takes two inputs. First is the string you want to evaluate the second is the base.

In your example the base is three therefore:

```
1*0 = 0
3*2 = 6
9*2 = 18

0 + 6 + 18 = 24
```