# I made a calculator in python but it is showing an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a python program but everytime I run it, it shows an error. It is some form of a int() with base 10 no idea what that is...

```
Enter a mathematical expression: 323+566
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ammar\PycharmProjects\Calculator\main.py", line 49, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\ammar\PycharmProjects\Calculator\main.py", line 44, in main
    output = solve_expression(expression)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ammar\PycharmProjects\Calculator\main.py", line 32, in solve_expression
    return int(tokens[0])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '323+566'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have no idea what that means or how to fix it any help would be appreciated.

```
def solve_expression(expression):

    # Remove spaces from the expression.
    expression = expression.replace(" ", "")

    # Check if the second operator is "/". If yes, ignore it.
    if expression[1] == "/":
        return int(expression[0])

    # Split the expression into a list of tokens.
    tokens = expression.split("*")

    # Evaluate the expression using BODMAS.
    for i in range(len(tokens)):
        if tokens[i] == "+":
            tokens[i - 1] = str(int(tokens[i - 1]) + int(tokens[i + 1]))
            tokens[i + 1] = ""
        elif tokens[i] == "-":
            tokens[i - 1] = str(int(tokens[i - 1]) - int(tokens[i + 1]))
            tokens[i + 1] = ""

    # Return the output of the expression.
    return int(tokens[0])


def main():
    # Get the mathematical expression from the user.
    expression = input("Enter a mathematical expression: ")

    # Solve the expression and print the output.
    output = solve_expression(expression)
    print(f"The output of the expression is {output}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Your  seem to somehow understand that you need to tokenize your expression but aren't tokenizing properly at all... How would splitting on `*` give you `+` or `-` as one of the tokens??

Comment: You cannot convert the string `323+566` to an integer.

Comment: The error means that `tokens[0]` contains the string `'323+566'`.  Since that is not a valid integer literal, passing it to `int()` gives the expected error, as you've seen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function `eval()`:

```
def solve_expression(expression):
    try:
        # Evaluate the expression
        result = eval(expression)
        return result
    except:
        # In the case of an invalid expression control the exception
        return "Invalid Expression"
    
def main():
    # Get the mathematical expression from the user.
    expression = input("Enter a mathematical expression: ")
    # Solve the expression and print the output.
    output = solve_expression(expression)
    print(f"The output of the expression is {output}")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

See the documentation of [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to get more info about this function.

Note that there are some risks to use `eval()` directly on the user input as it is explained [in this article](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval).

Comment: This snippet outputs the source as an unformatted string. Better to put it in a regular code block, or add a working test case.

Comment: Reminder: using eval() on user input is wildly unsafe. An input that looks like `__import__('os').system('rm all-your-files')` gives a bad actor the ability to run virtually any code they want on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are only splitting at `"*"`, but Im assuming you want to split at any math operator and also keep the operator in the output. What you wanna do is use a regular expression (or regex for short) to do the splitting instead so replace the line where you assign `tokens` with this (remember to add `import re` as well)

```py
# Split the expression into a list of tokens.
tokens = re.split(r"([\+\-\*/])", expression)
```

Short explanation to what is happening

`()` is used to capture the "splitter" in the output

`[]` is used to specify a group of character instead of only one

`\+\-\*/` are the actual split locations, an extra `\` is needed before the math operators to escape them, because they have a special meaning in regex coding.

Extra reading:

- https://regexr.com/
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html
- [What does base value do in int function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190060/what-does-base-value-do-in-int-function)

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is that you split the expression wrong.

Tip: a lot of code editors come with a debugger. You can use it to go through your code step by step and see the content of your variables. With a debugger it's easy to find the mistake in your code.

In this code:

```
for i in range(len(tokens)):
    if tokens[i] == "+":
        tokens[i - 1] = str(int(tokens[i - 1]) + int(tokens[i + 1]))
        tokens[i + 1] = ""
    elif tokens[i] == "-":
        tokens[i - 1] = str(int(tokens[i - 1]) - int(tokens[i + 1]))
        tokens[i + 1] = ""
```

you assume your tokens to be exactly "+" or "-" but it still contains the Numbers before and after the + or - sign. I.e. when I input the expression of your example, the token is "323+566". Instead you have to check if your token contains a "+" or "-" sign. You can do this with following code:

```
if "+" in token:
    #code for addition
elif "-" in token:
    #code for subtraction
```

You have to run this in a loop in case you get an expression like "1+1+1". But then you have to make sure no string contains an operator when converting to int. It's easy to get a mistake into something like this so I would go with a different approach.

I rewrote your calculator in a different way (see code below). The function `parse_expression(expression)` first checks if the expression is valid (does only contain numbers and operators).  Then it creates a list that contains all values and a list with all operators. With this approach I am sure the values are separated form the operators.

The following code performs the calculations for every operator. First, it loops through all `"*"` in the operators list. For every `"*"`, The index `i` of the `"*"` sign can be used to find the right numbers in the values list. It multiplies the number at `i` in the values list with the number at `i+1`. Then it writes the result in `values[i]` and deletes the following number in values, so the values list contains the product instead of the multiplier and multiplicand. This is done for every `"*"` in operators.

Then it does the same thing for the other operators. At the end, `values` only contains one number, this is the result of the calculation.

This calculation can definitely be done with fewer lines of code but I think the way I wrote it is better to understand.

Here is my code:

```
import re
import sys

def solve_expression(expression):

    (values, operators) = parse_expression(expression)

    #caluclations for the different operators
    while "*" in operators:
        i = operators.index("*")
        # replace values before and after * with result of calculation
        values[i] = values[i]*values[i+1]
        del values[i+1]
        #remove current operator
        del operators[i]

    while "/" in operators:
        i = operators.index("/")
        # replace values before and after / with result of calculation
        values[i] = values[i]/values[i+1]
        del values[i+1]
        #remove current operator
        del operators[i]

    while "+" in operators:
        i = operators.index("+")
        # replace values before and after + with result of calculation
        values[i] = values[i]+values[i+1]
        del values[i+1]
        #remove current operator
        del operators[i]

    while "-" in operators:
        i = operators.index("-")
        # replace values before and after - with result of calculation
        values[i] = values[i]-values[i+1]
        del values[i+1]
        #remove current operator
        del operators[i]

    # now values only contains one number, this is the result

    return values[0]
        
def parse_expression(expression): 
    
    # Remove spaces from the expression 
    expression = expression.replace(" ", "")
    #check if expression is vallid
    expression_pattern = re.compile("^([0-9]+[\+\/\-\*])+[0-9]+$")
    if not expression_pattern.match(expression):
        raise ValueError("Found unallowed character in expression")

    operators_regex = r"[\+\/\-\*]"  #regex of the possible operators
    # create list of all numbers
    values = re.split(operators_regex, expression)
    #string to int
    values = [ int(x) for x in values ]
    #create list of all operators
    operators = re.findall(operators_regex, expression)
    return (values, operators)

def main():
    # Get the mathematical expression from the user.
    expression = input("Enter a mathematical expression: ")

    # Solve the expression and print the output.
    try:
        output = solve_expression(expression)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        sys.exit(-1)
    
    print(f"The output of the expression is {output}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```